# What is the complexity of finding a generator for the cyclic elliptic curves?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve which is defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a prime number. If we know that $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is cycyclic, is there an algorithm to find its generator? If so, what is its complexity in the case where $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is composite number (actually it is a B-smooth number and I have B)?